# Manually installed python package but cannot import

Tags: python, anaconda, package

I tried to install the keras_contrib package in a virtual machine which does not allow internet access. So I manually unzip the package, navigate to folder and using `python setup.py install` to install it. After that I can find the package using `pip list`, however when I import the package cannot be found. And I cannot find the package folder in the *anaconda/lib/site-packages*.
(link of the package: https://github.com/keras-team/keras-contrib)

These are the screenshots at the beginning and ending during installation. 
[image]

[image]

Any suggestion? Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at your $PYTHONPATH environment variables. If you are using Mac or Linux, run `which python` command on your terminal. Also, you can look at the link below for a setup that is similar to your problem
https://github.com/sparklingpandas/sparklingpandas/wiki/setup.py-Install-for-Anaconda-Python

Comment: Thanks! I'm using windows, The $PYTHONPATH environment should be ok since I've installed others successfully.